# Formal Criteria for Network Complexity/Size Classification

Tags: networking, documentation

I seem to recall running across a "formal" criteria or a standardized method for helping to define and talk about a network's size or complexity - A set of generalized standards that people use when talking about networks (e.g., "I'm currently working for a company with a 'Stage II NETWORK'"). In fact, I'm pretty sure it was in a SF user's profile, but my google-fu has failed me here.

I'm aware of the different [network topologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology) and the LAN, MAN, and WAN [scale distinctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network#Scale) but I'm looking for something more specific.

- Is there a "formalized" set of criteria for specifying the complexity and size of a network?
- In the absence of such "formalized" criteria, what criteria do you use to classify networks with respect to size?

**Edit:**

Ah hah! Google comes through! I was thinking specifically of USENIX SAGE's [Job Descriptions and Definitions](http://www.sage.org/field/jobs-descriptions.html) -- although it turns out they are more specific to job description and less about network description so I'm still interested in hearing about what SF folks use for network description and classification criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In internet terms it is common to use "Tiers":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tier_1_network

Personally when talking to other peers the interesting metrics are used to describe networks.  Things like:

- Average Throughput (Gbps)
- ## of nodes/data centers
- ## of routers